# Etymology of the word 'finesse'

Tags: etymology, latin

According to Merriam-Webster, one of the definitions of the word *finesse* is as follows:

> refinement or delicacy of workmanship, structure, or texture

Now, based on the fact that the Latin base *fin* means *end* in English, I always intuitively assumed that the word had connotations with such concepts as: "finishing touch, attention to the end-product, and taking special care of the final details in a craft or situation". Are my perceptions of the word's associative properties a stretch of the imagination, or correctly guided?

Comment: It's not *fin* as in "end", it's *fin* as in "fine". Ultimately both are from the same Latin word, but that is entirely irrelevant to their present-day meaning in English, see [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The French loan-word *finesse* (also per the OED Pr. and Sp. *fineza*, Cat. *finesa*, Ital. *finezza*)  derives from common Romance **finitia*, from *fino* meaning — brace yourself now — “fine”.

So it just means fineness.  This in turn was a back-formation from *finire*, meaning to finish.

One might as well ask why fine finishings aren’t doubly ended.